# How to spliting datasets - Number of labels=150 does not match number of samples=600

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I have a data sample of 750x256.

```
Rows = 750
Columns = 256
```

If I split my data into 20%. I will have for `X_train` 600 samples and `y_train` 150 samples.

Then the problem would accure when doing `decisionTreeRegressor`

it will say `Number of y_train=150 does not match number of samples=600`

But if I split my test_size into 50%, then it will work.
is there a way to around this? I don't want to use 50% of my test_size.

Any help would be great!

here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import graphviz

#Load the data
dataset = pd.read_csv('new_york.csv')
dataset['Higher'] = dataset['2016-12'].gt(dataset['2016-11']).astype(int)
X = dataset.iloc[:, 6:254].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 255].values

#Taking care of missing data
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
imputer = Imputer(missing_values = 'NaN', strategy = 'mean', axis = 0)
imputer = imputer.fit(X[:, :248])
X[:, :248] = imputer.transform(X[:, :248])

#Split the data into train and test sets
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_test, y_train = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = .2,    random_state = 0)

#let's build our first model
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor, DecisionTreeClassifier, export_graphviz
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=6)
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf.score(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`train_test_split()` returns `X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test`, you have y_train and y_test in the wrong order.

If you use a split of 50% this is not causing an error because y_train and y_test will have the same size (but the wrong values obviously).